# Why is zipped faster than zip in Scala?

Tags: scala, performance, scala-collections, jmh, elementwise-operations

I have written some Scala code to perform an element-wise operation on a collection. Here I defined two methods that perform the same task. One method uses `zip` and the other uses `zipped`.

```
def ES (arr :Array[Double], arr1 :Array[Double]) :Array[Double] = arr.zip(arr1).map(x => x._1 + x._2)

def ES1(arr :Array[Double], arr1 :Array[Double]) :Array[Double] = (arr,arr1).zipped.map((x,y) => x + y)
```

To compare these two methods in terms of speed, I wrote the following code:

```
def fun (arr : Array[Double] , arr1 : Array[Double] , f :(Array[Double],Array[Double]) => Array[Double] , itr : Int) ={
  val t0 = System.nanoTime()
  for (i <- 1 to itr) {
       f(arr,arr1)
       }
  val t1 = System.nanoTime()
  println("Total Time Consumed:" + ((t1 - t0).toDouble / 1000000000).toDouble + "Seconds")
}
```

I call the `fun` method and pass `ES` and `ES1` as below:

```
fun(Array.fill(10000)(math.random), Array.fill(10000)(math.random), ES , 100000)
fun(Array.fill(10000)(math.random), Array.fill(10000)(math.random), ES1, 100000)
```

The results show that the method named `ES1` that uses `zipped` is faster than method `ES` that uses `zip`.
Based on these observations, I have two questions.

Why is `zipped` faster than `zip`?

Is there any even faster way to do element-wise operations on a collection in Scala?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125910/fastest-way-to-take-elementwise-sum-of-two-lists

Comment: Because JIT decided to optimize more aggressively the second time it saw 'fun' being invoked. Or because  GC decided to clean something up while ES was running. Or because your operating system decided that it had better things to do while your ES test was running. Could be anything, this microbenchmark is just not conclusive.

Comment: What are the results on your machine? How much faster?

Comment: For same population size and configurations, Zipped is taking 32 seconds while Zip is taking 44 seconds

Comment: Your results are meaningless. Use [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) if you must do micro-benchmarks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer your second question:

> Is there any more faster way to do element wise operation on a collection in Scala?

The sad truth is that despite it's conciseness, improved productivity, and resilience to bugs, is that functional languages aren't necessarily the most performant. In the OP's example, using higher order functions to define a projection to be executed against collections has overhead, and the tight loop amplifies this. As others have pointed out, additional storage allocation for intermediate and final results will also have overhead.

If performance is critical, although by no means universal, in cases like yours you can unwind concise functional code back into imperative equivalents in order to regain more direct control over memory usage and eliminating function call overheads.

In your specific example, the `zipped` sums can be performed imperatively by pre-allocating a fixed, mutable array of correct size (since zip stops when one of the collections runs out of elements), and then adding elements at the appropriate index together (since accessing array elements by ordinal index is a very fast operation).

By example, adding a third function, `ES3` to your test suite:

```
def ES3(arr :Array[Double], arr1 :Array[Double]) :Array[Double] = {
   val minSize = math.min(arr.length, arr1.length)
   val array = Array.ofDim[Double](minSize)
   for (i <- 0 to minSize - 1) {
     array(i) = arr(i) + arr1(i)
   }
  array
}
```

On my i7 I get the following response times:

```
OP ES Total Time Consumed:23.3747857Seconds
OP ES1 Total Time Consumed:11.7506995Seconds
--
ES3 Total Time Consumed:1.0255231Seconds
```

Even more heineous would be to do direct in-place mutation of the shorter of the two arrays, which would obviously corrupt the contents of this shorter array, so should only be implemented if the original arrays wouldn't be needed for further work by the caller:

```
def ES4(arr :Array[Double], arr1 :Array[Double]) :Array[Double] = {
   val minSize = math.min(arr.length, arr1.length)
   val array = if (arr.length < arr1.length) arr else arr1
   for (i <- 0 to minSize - 1) {
      array(i) = arr(i) + arr1(i)
   }
  array
}

Total Time Consumed:0.3542098Seconds
```

But obviously, direct mutation of arrays elements passed as parameters isn't in the spirit of Scala - this code smells of side effects.

To be honest, if you require this level of performance optimization in tight loops, you're likely better off writing these kinds of algorithms in Rust, Go or C.

Comment: I tested this and this version of code is much faster than mine. One thing to ask, we can not parallelize for loop. So what will be behavior of your code on cluster of 4 nodes.

Comment: There's nothing parallelized in my code above. Although this specific problem is parallelizable (since multiple threads could work on different sections of the arrays), there wouldn't be much point in such a simple operation on only 10k elements - the overhead of creating and synchronizing new threads would likely outweigh any benefit. To be honest, if you're require this level of performance optimization, you're likely better off writing these kinds of algorithms in Rust, Go or C.

Comment: It will be more scala-like and faster to use `Array.tabulate(minSize)(i => arr(i) + arr1(i))` to create your array

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh this is much slower one. Takes almost 9 seconds

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh although concise and elegant in respect of code, because of the lambda parameter, this will likely still require a stacked function call in the tight loop, causing the noted degradation. Performance would only be equivalent if the higher order function is somehow unwrapped and inlined.

Comment: `Array.tabulate` should be much faster than either `zip` or `zipped` here (and is in my benchmarks).

Comment: @StuartLC "Performance would only be equivalent if the higher order function is somehow unwrapped and inlined." This isn't really accurate. Even your `for` is desugared to a higher-order function call (`foreach`). The lambda will only be instantiated once in both cases.

Comment: @TravisBrown yes, but the lambda (closure) will be invoked 10000 times in the inner loop, which I believe will be a function call `someAnonLambda.invoke(i)` , with `i` being stacked, and `arr` and `arr1` being captured in the closure, likely resulting in additional heap-wrapped object. In order to avoid the overhead to get equivalent performance of our imperative loops, the lambda would need to be 'unpacked' and inlined. Would need to look at the byte code, and even the assembly to confirm, of course.

Comment: Ok, I think I see why we are missing eachother.@SarveshKumarSingh seemingly indicated that `tabulate` would be faster than an imperative loop, which I and OP immediately challenged (and you've since proven to be ~3 times slower). Whereas presumably @Sarvesh and yourself are referring to `zip` et al as a frame of reference

Comment: @StuartLC That seemingly resulted in some confusion. I don't think the `tabulate` method can be faster than `for-loop` because of the involved function and lambda-context-capture overhead but its both faster and more "scala-like" approach than the given `zip` and `zipped`.

Comment: @StuartLC Ah, makes sense, thanks for clarifying. :)

Answer (score 54):

None of the other answers mention the primary reason for the difference in speed, which is that the `zipped` version avoids 10,000 tuple allocations. As a couple of the other answers *do* note, the `zip` version involves an intermediate array, while the `zipped` version doesn't, but allocating an array for 10,000 elements isn't what makes the `zip` version so much worse—it's the 10,000 short-lived tuples that are being put into that array. These are represented by objects on the JVM, so you're doing a bunch of object allocations for things that you're immediately going to throw away.

The rest of this answer just goes into a little more detail about how you can confirm this.

### Better benchmarking

You really want to be using a framework like [jmh](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) to do any kind of benchmarking responsibly on the JVM, and even then the *responsibly* part is hard, although setting up jmh itself isn't too bad. If you have a `project/plugins.sbt` like this:

```
addSbtPlugin("pl.project13.scala" % "sbt-jmh" % "0.3.7")
```

And a `build.sbt` like this (I'm using 2.11.8 since you mention that's what you're using):

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)
```

Then you can write your benchmark like this:

```
package zipped_bench

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class ZippedBench {
  val arr1 = Array.fill(10000)(math.random)
  val arr2 = Array.fill(10000)(math.random)

  def ES(arr: Array[Double], arr1: Array[Double]): Array[Double] =
    arr.zip(arr1).map(x => x._1 + x._2)

  def ES1(arr: Array[Double], arr1: Array[Double]): Array[Double] =
    (arr, arr1).zipped.map((x, y) => x + y)

  @Benchmark def withZip: Array[Double] = ES(arr1, arr2)
  @Benchmark def withZipped: Array[Double] = ES1(arr1, arr2)
}
```

And run it with `sbt "jmh:run -i 10 -wi 10 -f 2 -t 1 zipped_bench.ZippedBench"`:

```
Benchmark                Mode  Cnt     Score    Error  Units
ZippedBench.withZip     thrpt   20  4902.519 ± 41.733  ops/s
ZippedBench.withZipped  thrpt   20  8736.251 ± 36.730  ops/s
```

Which shows that the `zipped` version gets about 80% more throughput, which is probably more or less the same as your measurements.

### Measuring allocations

You can also ask jmh to measure allocations with `-prof gc`:

```
Benchmark                                                 Mode  Cnt        Score       Error   Units
ZippedBench.withZip                                      thrpt    5     4894.197 ±   119.519   ops/s
ZippedBench.withZip:·gc.alloc.rate                       thrpt    5     4801.158 ±   117.157  MB/sec
ZippedBench.withZip:·gc.alloc.rate.norm                  thrpt    5  1080120.009 ±     0.001    B/op
ZippedBench.withZip:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space              thrpt    5     4808.028 ±    87.804  MB/sec
ZippedBench.withZip:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space.norm         thrpt    5  1081677.156 ± 12639.416    B/op
ZippedBench.withZip:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space          thrpt    5        2.129 ±     0.794  MB/sec
ZippedBench.withZip:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space.norm     thrpt    5      479.009 ±   179.575    B/op
ZippedBench.withZip:·gc.count                            thrpt    5      714.000              counts
ZippedBench.withZip:·gc.time                             thrpt    5      476.000                  ms
ZippedBench.withZipped                                   thrpt    5    11248.964 ±    43.728   ops/s
ZippedBench.withZipped:·gc.alloc.rate                    thrpt    5     3270.856 ±    12.729  MB/sec
ZippedBench.withZipped:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               thrpt    5   320152.004 ±     0.001    B/op
ZippedBench.withZipped:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space           thrpt    5     3277.158 ±    32.327  MB/sec
ZippedBench.withZipped:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space.norm      thrpt    5   320769.044 ±  3216.092    B/op
ZippedBench.withZipped:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space       thrpt    5        0.360 ±     0.166  MB/sec
ZippedBench.withZipped:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space.norm  thrpt    5       35.245 ±    16.365    B/op
ZippedBench.withZipped:·gc.count                         thrpt    5      863.000              counts
ZippedBench.withZipped:·gc.time                          thrpt    5      447.000                  ms
```

…where `gc.alloc.rate.norm` is probably the most interesting part, showing that the `zip` version is allocating over three times as much as `zipped`.

### Imperative implementations

If I knew that this method was going to be called in extremely performance-sensitive contexts, I'd probably implement it like this:

```
  def ES3(arr: Array[Double], arr1: Array[Double]): Array[Double] = {
    val minSize = math.min(arr.length, arr1.length)
    val newArr = new Array[Double](minSize)
    var i = 0
    while (i < minSize) {
      newArr(i) = arr(i) + arr1(i)
      i += 1
    }
    newArr
  }
```

Note that unlike the optimized version in one of the other answers, this uses `while` instead of a `for` since the `for` will still desugar into Scala collections operations. We can compare this implementation (`withWhile`), the other answer's optimized (but not in-place) implementation (`withFor`), and the two original implementations:

```
Benchmark                Mode  Cnt       Score      Error  Units
ZippedBench.withFor     thrpt   20  118426.044 ± 2173.310  ops/s
ZippedBench.withWhile   thrpt   20  119834.409 ±  527.589  ops/s
ZippedBench.withZip     thrpt   20    4886.624 ±   75.567  ops/s
ZippedBench.withZipped  thrpt   20    9961.668 ± 1104.937  ops/s
```

That's a really huge difference between the imperative and functional versions, and all of these method signatures are exactly identical and the implementations have the same semantics. It's not like the imperative implementations are using global state, etc. While the `zip` and `zipped` versions are more readable, I personally don't think there's any sense in which the imperative versions are against the "spirit of Scala", and I wouldn't hesitate to use them myself.

### With tabulate

Update: I added a `tabulate` implementation to the benchmark based on a comment in another answer:

```
def ES4(arr: Array[Double], arr1: Array[Double]): Array[Double] = {
  val minSize = math.min(arr.length, arr1.length)
  Array.tabulate(minSize)(i => arr(i) + arr1(i))
}
```

It's much faster than the `zip` versions, although still much slower than the imperative ones:

```
Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt      Score     Error  Units
ZippedBench.withTabulate  thrpt   20  32326.051 ± 535.677  ops/s
ZippedBench.withZip       thrpt   20   4902.027 ±  47.931  ops/s
```

This is what I'd expect, since there's nothing inherently expensive about calling a function, and because accessing array elements by index is very cheap.

Answer (score 9):

Consider [`lazyZip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#lazyZip[B](that:Iterable[B]):scala.collection.LazyZip2[A,B,Iterable.this.type])

```
(as lazyZip bs) map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```

instead of `zip`

```
(as zip bs) map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```

Scala 2.13 [added](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0) `lazyZip` in favour of `.zipped`

> Together with `.zip` on views, this replaces `.zipped` (now
>   deprecated). ([scala/collection-strawman#223](https://github.com/scala/collection-strawman/pull/223))

`zipped` (and hence `lazyZip`) is faster than `zip` because, as explained by [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59598415/5205022) and [Mike Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518296/5205022), `zip` followed by `map` will result in two separate transformations due to strictness, whilst `zipped` followed by `map` will result in a single transformation executed in one go due to laziness.

`zipped` gives `Tuple2Zipped`, and analysing [`Tuple2Zipped.map`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/e8521eb15dfb51f1fa26b579ebca7191b64ef33a/src/library/scala/runtime/Tuple2Zipped.scala#L48),

```
class Tuple2Zipped[...](val colls: (It1, It2)) extends ... {
  private def coll1 = colls._1
  private def coll2 = colls._2

  def map[...](f: (El1, El2) => B)(...) = {
    val b = bf.newBuilder(coll1)
    ...
    val elems1 = coll1.iterator
    val elems2 = coll2.iterator

    while (elems1.hasNext && elems2.hasNext) {
      b += f(elems1.next(), elems2.next())
    }

    b.result()
  }
```

we see the two collections `coll1` and `coll2` are iterated over and on each iteration the function `f` passed to `map` is applied along the way

```
b += f(elems1.next(), elems2.next())
```

without having to allocate and transform intermediary structures.

---

Applying Travis' benchmarking method, here is a comparison between new `lazyZip` and deprecated `zipped` where

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class ZippedBench {
  import scala.collection.mutable._
  val as = ArraySeq.fill(10000)(math.random)
  val bs = ArraySeq.fill(10000)(math.random)

  def lazyZip(as: ArraySeq[Double], bs: ArraySeq[Double]): ArraySeq[Double] =
    as.lazyZip(bs).map{ case (a, b) => a + b }

  def zipped(as: ArraySeq[Double], bs: ArraySeq[Double]): ArraySeq[Double] =
    (as, bs).zipped.map { case (a, b) => a + b }

  def lazyZipJavaArray(as: Array[Double], bs: Array[Double]): Array[Double] =
    as.lazyZip(bs).map{ case (a, b) => a + b }

  @Benchmark def withZipped: ArraySeq[Double] = zipped(as, bs)
  @Benchmark def withLazyZip: ArraySeq[Double] = lazyZip(as, bs)
  @Benchmark def withLazyZipJavaArray: ArraySeq[Double] = lazyZipJavaArray(as.toArray, bs.toArray)
}
```

gives

```
[info] Benchmark                          Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
[info] ZippedBench.withZipped            thrpt   20  20197.344 ± 1282.414  ops/s
[info] ZippedBench.withLazyZip           thrpt   20  25468.458 ± 2720.860  ops/s
[info] ZippedBench.withLazyZipJavaArray  thrpt   20   5215.621 ±  233.270  ops/s
```

`lazyZip` seems to perform a bit better than `zipped` on `ArraySeq`. Interestingly, notice significantly degraded performance when using `lazyZip` on `Array`.

Comment: lazyZip is available in Scala 2.13.1. Currently I am using Scala 2.11.8

Answer (score 5):

You should always be cautious with performance measurement because of JIT compilation, but a likely reason is that `zipped` is lazy and extracts elements from the original `Array` vaules during the `map` call, whereas `zip` creates a new `Array` object and then calls `map` on the new object.