# Scala : function to measure the runtime of any other function

Tags: java, scala

I want to write a function, which prints the runtime of any other function which take as an argument along with parameters. Example my idea in python for a better understanding:

```
def runtimer(func , *args, **kwargs):
    start = time.time()
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    print(time.time() - start)
    return result


runtimer(time.sleep, 1)

Output: 1.000108242034912
```

I'm trying to use `val: _*` parameter, but it implements "all or nothing". In another way I checked `print` function in source scala github, but I did not find anything applicable to my question.

I would like to know if this is possible to solve on scala or get any advice. A java implementation will also be useful.

Thanks!

UPD: I will leave here some most useful references: the first for the most similar implementation, second maximum correct for runtime calculating on JVM (by comment):
1) [How to profile methods in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160001/how-to-profile-methods-in-scala)
2) [Scala : function to measure the runtime of any other function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60546924/scala-function-to-measure-the-runtime-of-any-other-function)

The question is still open, I'm waiting for discussions

Comment: @MarioGalic I believe the accepted answer of the duplicate is totally wrong, that is not the correct way to benchmark on the JVM. I believe it would better to link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598239/why-is-zipped-faster-than-zip-in-scala/59600699#59600699)

Comment: I’ll clarify that not high accuracy is important, that is, this fencing is necessary to calculate the operating time of algorithms that work for more than a minute and accuracy can be important at +-10%. Now I use this code:
time = System.currentTimeMillis()
func()
println("Runtime: " + System.currentTimeMillis() - time)

Comment: If you want a Java profiling function, you should break that up into a separate question. It's entirely independent of the Scala profiling function.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've updated [How to profile methods in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9160001/5205022) with hopefully correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035954/5205022) based on Travis'.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you have to use HOFs (higher-order functions).
Those are functions which take other functions as parameters.
Here is an example of how it can be done for function with one parameter.

```
 def measure(yourFunction: (Int) => Int, arg1: Integer): Double = {
   val startTime = System.nanoTime()
   yourFunction(arg1)
   System.nanoTime() - startTime 
 }
```

As you can see, this function measures time for functions which take Int as a parameter and return Int.
I've translated your Python code to Scala

NJ

Comment: Yes it's work, but I want to write a universal function, not only for 1 or only 2 parameters. Someone mark this answer with good reference for me (with call-by-name):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160001/how-to-profile-methods-in-scala